# What is the best way to check if a product id is valid in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

For a backend module I have the need to check if a product id is valid, that is: is there a product with that id? I've found two solutions for that, but I'm not very happy with either one:

1. Directy query the `catalog_product_entity` table. Very fast but definitely not very elegant and I fear there might be issues I'm not aware of.
2. Use the following code:

   ```
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productID)
   if ($product->getId()) {
     //valid id
   }
   else {
     //not a valid id
   }
   ```

   This should work but it's painfully slow, because I have to check several IDs at once. And since I don't need the actual product data, it doesn't really make sense to load it.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks [benmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833795/benmarks) and [james](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163653/james), you've pointed me in the right direction and I just combined your approches:

```
$productIds = array(16,17,18,19,290993,25    /*...*/);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$productIds));

$foundIds = $collection->getAllIds();

var_dump($foundIds); /* each array value should be a valid ID */
```

For some reason, getAllIds() returns Ids as strings rather than ints, but that's fine.

Comment: PHP will interpret strings as ints if the context is correct, and you can pass an int as a string in Magento without an error. There is no need to filter the collection by `entity_id` as it will only return valid entity ID's. I usually only call `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()` in case the model has been overridden. I've updated my answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 5):

```
$productIds = array(16,17,18,19,290993,25    /*...*/);

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in'=>$productIds))->load();

$foundIds = array_intersect($productIds,array_keys($collection->toArray()));

var_dump($foundIds); /* each array value should be a valid ID */
```

Comment: This somehow doesn't work for me... `$collection->toArray()` always returns an empty array even when the productIds are valid.

Comment: The collection has to be loaded after adding the filter and before before fetching the array.

Comment: Although the solution works, it adds a layer of complexity not needed. Magento has the functionality in `$collection->getAllIds()`

Comment: @james - that will get all existing Ida, not just the filtered ones.

Comment: @Aufroller, yes, I had this in my IDE but failed to add to post. Edited, thank you!

Comment: @james - I revisited what you said, and absolutely, you are correct. When I looked at the method definition I swear that I thought I read that the `Zend_Db_Select::ORDER` was being reset as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$collection->getAllIds();
```

You'll get an array of all the product IDs, and you can then do an `in_array` to check for validity. Take a look at

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection
```

to see how it's done.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
function isProductIdValid($productId)
{
    // Allows model overrides (other modules) to work correctly.
    // Returns all valid IDs
    $collection  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $productIds = $collection->getAllIds();

    if (in_array($productId, $productIds)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: depending on the total number of products in the catalogue this might not be very efficient

Comment: @Aufroller true, collections do slow down when the product count goes into the tens of thousands. However, using a collection is best practice as there might be other modules that observe events and manipulate the data / override the class. It makes for easier cross-installation use too

Comment: That's why I didn't want to query the database directly. I've just added a new solution based on your approach and @benmarks. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

For having it fast, raw queries seem definitely the fastest to me always :-)

But maybe preload all id's like this could help?

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns(array('entity_id'));

$ids = array();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
  $ids[] = $product->getId();
}
```

Then you can just test with the in_array method if an id exists.